# Elastic Beanstalk over managing the parts with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

So I have an environment that has elastic beanstalk for managing it's webservers.  And I terraformed it.  But I was asking myself.  What am I gaining by terraforming ELB versus just terraforming the resources directly (ASG,LC,LB,...) ?

Edit: I am talking from the perspective of creating a brand new env... should I both with ELB or not.. and if so, why?

Answer (score 0):

EB is a [Platform as a service (PaaS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) product from the AWS. This means that when you choose to use EB, you are letting **AWS manage all the resources** for you. They include EC2 instances, security groups, load balancers, autoscaling groups and more.

Therefore, its a bad practice to tinker with these resources
"manually" outside of EB control and knowledge, because changing your resources manually leads to **configuration drift** - EB configuration settings will not match actual settings.

So if just import resources individually to TF you are not only sacrificing the PaaS capabilities of EB, but also you are likely to introduce drift in the long run. Thus, when you bring EB env into TF you should use [Elastic Beanstalk](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_configuration_template) configurations to keep everything under control of EB.

Having everything controlled by EB also simplifies a lot of things. Lets say you want to change from single-instance to load-balance EB env type. Using EB configuration it is just one line of code to change. But doing this "manually" requires a lot of work which is prone to errors.

Comment: Yeah, I meant more like... since I am using terraform.. should I use an EB at all, or just create and manage it all with terraform.  EB seems like another layer that adds complexity, but if it has enough gains, that complexity is worth it.  But I am not sure what those gains really are.

Comment: @Randell Terraform is not PaaS. It has totally different use cases from EB and will not do for you what EB can do. If you want to manage and provision entire infrastructure then of course you don't need EB. So it comes down to what you want to do? Do you want want setup everything from zero for your application and keep maintaining it yourself?

Comment: The issue I am having is seeing clearly what EB is doing that terraform doesn't. I have a feeling that our processes may not be using EB the way it is intended thus making them less obvious.  So far I see basically version management and deliver of the application to the instances...  We already have a different mechanism we use for services that could handle that on reboot... ASG's have refresh mechanisms that can trigger that.  But there must be more that EB gives that I am missing.